# How to set default libraries for all android studio projects

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

There are some libraries that are a crucial part of android development 
The question is can we set some defaults libraries to be added to gradle when we are making a new project (I know there some ways like templates but they need also the same procedure somehow)

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidStudio there are some templates.
You can manage them to add some dependencies, but I discourage this way since the templates can change in the later releases, each update can override your files, then it is not so simple to have a good maintenance.

It is not equivalent and may be it not your aim but you can copy an external gradle file in your projects and then just add the dependencies in a very short time.

Something like `gradleScript/dependecies.gradle`

```
ext {
    //Version
    supportLibrary = '27.x.x'

    //Support Libraries dependencies
    supportDependencies = [
            design           :         "com.android.support:design:${supportLibrary}",
            recyclerView     :         "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            cardView         :         "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            appCompat        :         "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            supportAnnotation:         "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibrary}",
    ]
}
```

Add in your top-level `build.gradle`:

```
// Load dependencies
apply from: 'gradleScript/dependencies.gradle'
```

And then in each `module/build.gradle` just add your dependencies:

```
// Module build file

dependencies {
    //......
    compile supportDependencies.appCompat
    compile supportDependencies.design
}
```